# How to debug code and visualize the execution

Tags: python, debugging, visual-studio-code

I'm taking open-source class. I am given doctests and a CLI to test my code and see if it passes, however, how can I visualize my code to see what is happening? For instance, I am having a hard time understanding how the `for loop` is working and I would like to see what list is assigned in each recursion.

The file has many functions so running `-m doctest` isn't ideal and also doesn't show the execution. When I run debug mode in vs code and set a breakpoint at the function, it never steps into the function. I imagine this is because in the file I never call `nut_finder()` but I don't want to start adding to the source code since that would defeat the purpose of the doctest. I can also run python interactively but that too won't show me how the code is executing.

The only solution I have found is to use a [tool](http://pythontutor.com/composingprograms.html#code=def%20nut_finder%28t%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%22%22%22Returns%20True%20if%20t%20contains%20a%20node%20with%20the%20value%20'nut'%20and%0A%20%20%20%20False%20otherwise.%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%3E%3E%3E%20scrat%20%3D%20tree%28'nut'%29%0A%20%20%20%20%3E%3E%3E%20nut_finder%28scrat%29%0A%20%20%20%20True%0A%20%20%20%20%3E%3E%3E%20sproul%20%3D%20tree%28'roots',%20%5Btree%28'branch1',%20%5Btree%28'leaf'%29,%20tree%28'nut'%29%5D%29,%20tree%28'branch2'%29%5D%29%0A%20%20%20%20%3E%3E%3E%20nut_finder%28sproul%29%0A%20%20%20%20True%0A%20%20%20%20%3E%3E%3E%20numbers%20%3D%20tree%281,%20%5Btree%282%29,%20tree%283,%20%5Btree%284%29,%20tree%285%29%5D%29,%20tree%286,%20%5Btree%287%29%5D%29%5D%29%0A%20%20%20%20%3E%3E%3E%20nut_finder%28numbers%29%0A%20%20%20%20False%0A%20%20%20%20%3E%3E%3E%20t%20%3D%20tree%281,%20%5Btree%28'nut',%5Btree%28'not%20nut'%29%5D%29%5D%29%0A%20%20%20%20%3E%3E%3E%20nut_finder%28t%29%0A%20%20%20%20True%0A%20%20%20%20%22%22%22%0A%20%20%20%20if%20label%28t%29%20%3D%3D%20'nut'%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20True%0A%20%20%20%20for%20b%20in%20branches%28t%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20nut_finder%28b%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20True%0A%20%20%20%20return%20False%0A%0A%23%20Tree%20ADT%0Adef%20tree%28label,%20branches%3D%5B%5D%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%22%22%22Construct%20a%20tree%20with%20the%20given%20label%20value%20and%20a%20list%20of%20branches.%22%22%22%0A%20%20%20%20for%20branch%20in%20branches%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20assert%20is_tree%28branch%29,%20'branches%20must%20be%20trees'%0A%20%20%20%20return%20%5Blabel%5D%20%2B%20list%28branches%29%0A%0Adef%20label%28tree%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%22%22%22Return%20the%20label%20value%20of%20a%20tree.%22%22%22%0A%20%20%20%20return%20tree%5B0%5D%0A%0Adef%20branches%28tree%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%22%22%22Return%20the%20list%20of%20branches%20of%20the%20given%20tree.%22%22%22%0A%20%20%20%20return%20tree%5B1%3A%5D%0A%0Adef%20is_tree%28tree%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%22%22%22Returns%20True%20if%20the%20given%20tree%20is%20a%20tree,%20and%20False%20otherwise.%22%22%22%0A%20%20%20%20if%20type%28tree%29%20!%3D%20list%20or%20len%28tree%29%20%3C%201%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20False%0A%20%20%20%20for%20branch%20in%20branches%28tree%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20not%20is_tree%28branch%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20False%0A%20%20%20%20return%20True%0A%0Adef%20is_leaf%28tree%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%22%22%22Returns%20True%20if%20the%20given%20tree's%20list%20of%20branches%20is%20empty,%20and%20False%0A%20%20%20%20otherwise.%0A%20%20%20%20%22%22%22%0A%20%20%20%20return%20not%20branches%28tree%29%0A%0A&cumulative=true&mode=edit&origin=composingprograms.js&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D) that visualizes the code, however, this requires me to manually copy and paste stuff. This also will become a problem from large applications and multi-file applications. So in short, how can I learn the right way to debug my code.

```
# lab05.py
def nut_finder(t):
"""Returns True if t contains a node with the value 'nut' and
False otherwise.

>>> scrat = tree('nut')
>>> nut_finder(scrat)
True
>>> sproul = tree('roots', [tree('branch1', [tree('leaf'), tree('nut')]), tree('branch2')])
>>> nut_finder(sproul)
True
>>> numbers = tree(1, [tree(2), tree(3, [tree(4), tree(5)]), tree(6, [tree(7)])])
>>> nut_finder(numbers)
False
>>> t = tree(1, [tree('nut',[tree('not nut')])])
>>> nut_finder(t)
True
"""
if label(t) == 'nut':
    return True
for b in branches(t):
    if nut_finder(b):
        return True
return False
```

Answer (score 0):

I think python 3.7 and up: type `breakpoint()` right where you want it to stop. It is a shortcut for using pdb module (https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html).